# Efficiency in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, performance

So my teacher tells me that I should compute intermediate results as needed on the fly rather than storing them, because the speed of processors nowadays is much more faster than the speed of memory.

So when we compute an intermediate result, we also need to use some memory right ? Can anyone please explain it to me ?

Comment: I'd leave it to the compiler if I were you. It may or may not choose to use registers for storage.

Comment: What @Bathsheba said: I think the teacher meant that the compiler may use registers for immediate store, thus not having to store the results in memory. But with today's sophisticated compilers you really can't know unless you deassemble the code. I suggest you write a simple program in two versions, with storing the intermediate results and not and see how the deassembled code differs.

Comment: I'd add that for most tasks, writing clean, easy-to-understand, maintainable code is going to be more important than trying to squeeze small performance increases out of your source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So when we compute an intermediate result, we also need to use some memory right ? Can anyone please explain it to me?

There are several levels of memory in a computer. The layers look like this

1. registers – the CPU does all the calculations on this and access is instant
2. Caches - memory that's tightly coupled to the CPU core; all memory accesses to main system memory go through the cache actually and to the program it looks like if the data goes and comes from system memory. If the data is present in the cache and the access is well aligned the access is almost instant as well and hence very fast.
3. main system memory - connected to the CPU through a memory controller and shared by the CPU cores in a system. Accessing main memory introduces latencies through addressing and the limited bandwidth between memory and CPUs

When you work with in-situ calculated intermediary results those often never leave the registers or may go only as far as the cache and thus are not limited by the available system memory bandwidth or blocked by memory bus arbitration or address generation interlock.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. What if the intermediate results size is quite large (e.g., 3D vertices of some model object) ? Can it be the case that the intermediary results leave the register and caches and will be stored in main system memory ? If that is the case, will computing intermediate results still be better ?

Comment: And also we should expect that intermediate results will be accessed many time right ? So after finishing calculating the intermediate results, will the intermediate results always stay in registers or caches ?

Comment: @laituan245: There's only a limited number of registers and the caches are quite small. So no, intermediary results will not stay there. A 3D model is not the kind of intermediary data your teacher was talking about. This is more about intermediary results of rather simple calculations, which as well could be precomputed.

Comment: @laituan245: For example say you have a lookup-table of N entries, where each entry can be calculated by a rather simple formula based on just the index. Say something like `a(N) = 3*sin(2*N - 0.3) - tan(1/N)` (that's just an example). On a modern CPU it would take more clock cycles to fetch a precomputed `a(N)` from memory, than to simply recompute it for the next step. I don't know if you know already about Big-O notation, but as a handy rule, everything that computes in O(1) in less than 20 clock cycles (any definitely for anything computing in less than 10) should not be kept in memory.

Comment: @laituan245: To determine the amount of clock cycles a computation takes you have to look at the generated assembly code and for each instruction look in the CPU's manual how many clock cycles the instruction takes to execute.

Answer (score 5):

your teacher is right **speed of processors nowadays is much more faster than the speed of memory.**  Access to RAM is slower what access to the internal memory: cache, registers, etc.

Suppose you want to compute a trigonometric function: sin(x). To do this you can either **call a function** (math library offers one, or implement your own) which is **computing the value**; or you can **use a lookup table** stored in memory to get the result which means **storing the intermediate values** (sort of).

Calling a function will result in executing a number of instructions, while using a lookup table will result in fewer instructions (getting the address of the LUT, getting the offset to the desired element, reading from address+offset). I`n this case, storing the intermediate values is faster`

But if you were to do `c = a+b`, computing the value will be much faster than reading it from somewhere in RAM. Notice that in this case the number of instructions to be executed would be similar.

So while it is true that access to RAM is slower, whether it's worth accessing RAM instead of doing the computation is a sensible question and several things need to be considered: number of instructions to be executed, if the computation happens in a loop and you can take advantage the architectures pipeline, cache memory, etc.
There is no one answer, you need to analyze each situation individually.

Comment: Have you tried the sin function example? I think you might be surprised...

Answer (score 3):

Your teacher's advice is oversimplifying advice on a complex topic.

If you think of "intermediate" as a *single term* (in the arithmetical sense of the word), then ask yourself, is your code re-using that term anywhere else ? I.e. if you have code like:

```
void calculate_sphere_parameters(double radius, double & area, double & volume)
{
    area = 4 * (4 * acos(1)) * radius * radius;
    volume = 4 * (4 * acos(1)) * radius * radius * radius / 3;
}
```

should you instead write:

```
void calculate_sphere_parameters(double radius, double & area, double *volume)
{
    double quarter_pi = acos(1);
    double pi = 4 * quarter_pi;
    double four_pi = 4 * pi;
    double four_thirds_pi = four_pi / 3;
    double radius_squared = radius * radius;
    double radius_cubed = radius_squared * radius;

    area = four_pi * radius_squared;
    volume = four_thirds_pi * radius_cubed;    // maybe use "(area * radius) / 3" ?
}
```

It's not unlikely that a modern optimizing compiler will emit the same binary code for these two. I leave it to the reader to determine what they prefer to see in the sourcecode ...

The same is true for a lot of simple arithmetics (at the very least, if no function calls are involved in the calculation). In addition to that, modern compilers and/or CPU instruction sets might have the ability to do "offset" calculations for free, i.e. something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    do_something_with(i, i + 25, i + 314159);
}
```

will turn out the same as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    int j = i + 25;
    int k = i + 314159;
    do_something_with(i, j, k);
}
```

So the main rule should be, if your code's readability doesn't benefit from creating a new variable to hold the result of a "temporary" calculation, it's probably overkill to use one.
If, on the other hand, you're using `i + 12345` a dozen times in ten lines of code ... name it, and comment why this strange hardcoded offset is so important.

Remember just because your *source code* contains a variable doesn't mean the binary code as emitted by the compiler will allocate memory for this variable. The compiler might come to the conclusion that the value isn't even used (and completely discard the calculation assigning it), or it might come to the conclusion that it's "only an intermediate" (never used later where it would've to be retrieved from memory) and so store it in a register, to overwrite after "last use". It's far more efficiently to do something like calculate the value `i + 1` each time you need it than to retrieve it from a memory location.

My advice would be:

- keep your code readable first and foremost - too many variables rather obscure than help.
- don't bother saving "simple" intermediates - addition/subtraction or scaling by powers of two is pretty much a "free" operation
- if you reuse the same value ("arithmetic term") in multiple places, save it if it is expensive to calculate (for example involves function calls, a long sequence of arithmetics, or a lot of memory accesses like an array checksum).

Answer (score 0):

This hurts me.

Ask your teacher (or better, don't, because with his level of competence in programming I wouldn't trust him), whether he has measured it, and what the difference was. The rule when you are programming for speed is: If you haven't measured it, and measured it before and after a change, then what you are doing is purely based on presumption and worthless.

In reality, an optimising compiler will take the code that you write and translate it to the fastest possible machine code. As a result, it is unlikely that there is *any* difference in code or speed.

On the other hand, using intermediate variables will make complex expressions easier to understand and easier to get right, and it makes debugging a lot easier. If your huge complex expression gives what looks like the wrong result, intermediate variables make it possible to check the calculation bit by bit and find where the error is.

Now even if he was right and removing intermediate variables made your code faster, and even if anyone cared about the speed difference, he would be wrong: Making your code readable and easier to debug gets you to a correctly working version of the code quicker (and if it doesn't work, nobody cares how fast it is). Now if it turns out that the code needs to be faster, the time you saved will allow you to make changes that make it *really* faster.